# Validation with doctype inside

Tags: xml, xslt, dtd

Im trying to validate an XML file with an XSL file. And using a live validation that I found online.

I get this error when Im validation

> Unknown error type: java.io.FileNotFoundException

But when I remove the doctype line ( `<!DOCTYPE thesaurus SYSTEM "dictionary.dtd">` ) its working without any problems.

Is this a common validation problem ? or am I doing something wrong?
When Im validation my XML with my DTD I dont get any errors.

Comment: After I added my answer, I realized that you said you're validating your XML file with XSL. How do you validate with XSLT?

Comment: With the online validator
http://jmeware.com/LiveXsl.jsp

Answer (score 0):

You only have a system identifier pointing to the DTD, so it's most likely an issue of the online tool not being able to find the DTD. (What online validation are you using?)

What you can try doing instead is putting the DTD in the internal subset:

```
<!DOCTYPE thesaurus [
<!--contents of dictionary.dtd should go here-->
]>
```

Comment: I was thinking about that to, but I would like to have the dtd on a external file. That's why I'm struggling with it :)
I'm using this live validator

http://jmeware.com/LiveXsl.jsp

Comment: @FelipeOtarola - That website doesn't do validation. It only does XSLT transforms. The only way to use an external DTD while doing transforms with that website is to put the DTD somewhere it can find it. Like on a website where you can supply a URL to the DTD.

Comment: @FelipeOtarola: And, based on your latest question, should I even say this, the website or the XSLT processor do not perform translation... Validation is not translation from one langiage to another.